# How do I show one of six elements using the code provided?

Tags: javascript

I found a section of code that I am trying to edit to work for my site. instead of showing one of 2 elements, I need to show one of six. How do I do that with this code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var value1 = 'sub1';
    var value2 = 'sub2';
    var value3 = 'sub3';
    var value4 = 'sub4';
    var value5 = 'sub5';
    var value6 = 'sub6';
    var chosenValue = Math.random() < 0.5 ? value1 : value2;
    var chosenDiv = document.getElementById(chosenValue);
    chosenDiv.style.display = "block";
</script>
```

HTML looks like this:

```
<h2 id="sub1">One</h2>
<h2 id="sub2">Two</h2>
<h2 id="sub3">Three</h2>
<h2 id="sub4">Four</h2>
<h2 id="sub5">Five</h2>
<h2 id="sub6">Six</h2>
```

Comment: Show what? Show what where? Please be more precise.

Comment: So you want any 1 from 6 element need to show randomly?

Comment: He wants to show a random element from `value1` to `value6`. If so use an array and `array.length` within `math.random()`.

Comment: My main question is you are selecting one of the six elements and displaying just that one and the rest stay hidden? Or are you picking a value from one of this six variables and putting that inside a div?

Comment: Math.floor(Math.random()*6+1) this would be suitable for generating a random number between 1 and 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array!

```
var values = ["sub1","sub2","sub3","sub4","sub5","sub6"];
var chosenValue = values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
var chosenDiv = document.getElementById(chosenValue);
chosenDiv.style.display = "block";
```

What happens here is you have all your values in an array, and you pick one via a random index using arrays length as a boundary. Then you just apply the style.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly the answer I was working on. Put the values into an array.

Comment: @NickDugger For these questions it's really about who answers the fastest. We all know it's going to be using an array.